# How can I select the child of the third previous DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
<div ><a href='#' id='my_target'>Link</a></div>
<div></div>
<div><div></div></div>
<div><div id='my_div'></div></div>
```

How can I select `#my_target`, when the event is triggered from `my_div`?

I tried things such as `prev().prev().prev().children()`, but I can't get it to work, and I want something more efficient.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use $("#my_target") ?

Comment: @gabitzish: Probably that's just there to be used as a pointer in this example.

Comment: Hi there, I got an answer below. I wanted to use $(this), that's why $("#my_target") would not have helped me. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also just use relative paths:
HTML:

```
<div><a href='#' id='my_target'>Link</a></div>
<div></div>
<div><div></div></div>
<div><div id='my_div'></div></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($("#my_div").parent().parent().children(':first'));
});
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Bf6g/

Comment: Hi thanks for your solution. Im just wondering what console.log will do? Even though I understand it's a debugging feature. Thanks again

Comment: Ah, sorry. This is a feature that's built into most web browsers nowadays, (chrome web debugging tool, firefox/firebug and internet explorer web development toolbar. It allows to quickly log an element and show what it is, instead of doing stuff like alert(), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I did it like so:

```
​var md = $("#my_div");​​​​​​​​​
var anchor = $(md.parent().prevAll().last().find("a"));
console.log(anchor);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t9HZz/

[`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) grabs all the parent's siblings, and then we grab the last one with `last()` because it adds the siblings in reverse order, then we can just find the link from there.

Although in your example, the link does have an id so you could just do `$("#my_target")` in this specific example.